# triple and square functions don't display correctly

Tags: python, for-loop

I was asked to write two functions - `triple` and `square` - the first should multiply its parameter by three and the latter raises its parameter to the power of two. At first, a "for loop" should iterate through values 1 to 10, and for each value prints its `triple` and its `square`. After that I need to modify this "for loop" so that it stops iteration when the `square` of a value is larger than the `triple` of the value, without printing anything in the last iteration. The test cases check that both functions `triple` and `square` are called exactly once per iteration.

I wrote a code, but I suspect it doesn't satisfy the given condition, because it crashed the test cases:

```
def triple(a):
    tr = a*3
    return tr

def square(a):
    sq = a**2
    return sq

for i in range(1,11):
    t1 = triple(i)
    s1 = square(i)
    #print(f"triple({i})=={triple(i)} square({i})=={square(i)}")
    if s1 > t1:
        break
    else:
        print(f"triple({i})=={triple(i)} square({i})=={square(i)}")
```

How could I improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your tests check that you only call triple and square once per iteration, you have to change your print statement to use t1 and s1. So it'd look like:

```
print(f"triple({i}) == {t1} square({i}) == {s1}")
```

The way you have it now, you're calling the functions again while printing.

Comment: I edited my code taking into account your recommendations (they are right, indeed), but still got an error:

Failed: test.test_triple_square.TripleSquare.test_calls
     1 not found in [3, 10] : Wrong number of printed lines: 1!
Failed: test.test_triple_square.TripleSquare.test_calls2
     1 not found in [3] : Wrong number of printed lines: 1!

I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, as I am new to Python, but in your formatted string, you should try to use the variables t1 and s1 instead of calling the function so that it uses the squared value of I on the iterations of the for loop, just a thought. Sorry if this did not help!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def triple(num):
    a = num*3
    return a

def square(num):
    b = num**2
    return b

def main():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        trip = triple(i)
        sqre = square(i)
        if sqre>trip:
            break
        else:
            print(f"triple({i})=={trip} square({i})=={sqre}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The test requires your functions to be global